# Turning a uiimage to int array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I currently have code that takes a UIImage in and return an NSArray

```
-(NSArray*)getPixelsFromImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    NSMutableArray *pixelData=[NSMutableArray new];
    for (int y = 0; y<image.size.height; y+=1) {
        for (int x = 0; x<image.size.width; x+=1) {
            CGImageRef tmp = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, CGRectMake(x, y, 1, 1));
            UIImage *part=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:tmp];
            [pixelData addObject:part];
        }

    }
    return [pixelData copy];
}
```

I was wondering how I could take this NSArray that it returns and turn it into an array of integers?

Comment: What does an array of integers that you are talking about look like?  And how does your code have anything to do with it?

Comment: The code returns an NSArray of pixels from the UIImage. I want to take those pixels and just make them into an int array. Is there such a thing? Or is this pixel array already just numbers? In the end I would like to take the integer array and map it to a scale of numbers to I can get a representation of the pixel values on like a scale of 0 to 1000.